# Why void functions are allowed in left part of assignment in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following Typescript code:

```
var action = function action(): void {
    //do things
};

var res = action();
```

Why is it fine for TS compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is because, `void` is a type in Typescript and it has it's set of possible values, which are `undefined` and `null`, therefore can be used in left part of assignments.

I find the fact that it allowed to use values typed as `void` in assignments could lead to severe errors. For example if one had a function returning something meaningful was refactored to return `void`, there will be no error at compile time.

For the reference Typescript 1.4 language spec have the following to say about Void type:

> The Void type [...] represents the absence
>   of a value and is used as the return type of functions with no return
>   value.  The only possible values for the Void type are null and
>   undefined. The Void type is a subtype of the Any type and a supertype
>   of the Null and Undefined types, but otherwise Void is unrelated to
>   all other types.
>   NOTE: We might consider disallowing declaring
>   variables of type Void as they serve no useful purpose. However,
>   because Void is permitted as a type argument to a generic type or
>   function it is not feasible to disallow Void properties or parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Why void functions are allowed in left part of assignment in Typescript?

Simply because they are not disallowed. Note that there isn't must useful (bad) stuff you can do with a void variable e.g.

```
var action = function action(): void {};
var res = action();
res.foo; // Error
```

Comment: It does not really answer my questions and I disagree that its that harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
// Generic function for perf measuring
function time<T>(f: () => T): T {
  var start = Date.now();
  var result = f();
  console.log('It took ' + (Date.now() - start) + ' to run');
  return f;
}

function doSomething(): void { }

time(doSomething);
```

If we think about generic functions as being type-specific instantiations of a template (note: they aren't), `result` is of type `void` when `time` is invoked with `doSomething`. Clearly the world doesn't explode when that happens, so having a variable of type `void` isn't something that *must* be prevented.

Here's another example:

```
declare function doNothing(): void;
declare function doOneThing(): void;
declare function doManyThings(): void;

function doSomething(x: number) {
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
            return doNothing();
        case 1:
            return doOneThing();
        default:
            return doManyThings();
    }
}
```

Here, we want to make it so that if we change the return type of `doSomething`, we have to update the return types of `doNothing`/`doOneThing`/`doManyThings`. Again, here's the general principle that a `void` *value* is moving around with no ill effect. This example is *not* artificial - it's adapted from some code in the TypeScript compiler itself.

Let's refactor that code a bit:

```
function doSomething(x: number) {
    if (x > 1) {
        return doManyThings();
    } else {
        // result: void!
        var result = x === 0 ? doNothing() : doOneThing();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Why should this harmless refactoring introduce an error? What's the point? If we try to access any properties of `result`, that will be an error. If we don't try to access any properties of `result`, it's likely we're doing nothing wrong and shouldn't be bothered.